# Service-worker breaks the Internet

Tags: service-worker

Imagine you have a PWA with a service-worker on **foo.fr**.

You decide you want to change your domain name for **bar.fr**.
So you decide to just 301 redirect all traffic from **foo.fr** to **bar.fr**.

It will work like a charm for all new users who go on **foo.fr**, they'll be redirected to **bar.fr**.

BUT users who previously went on **foo.fr** will have the cache served by service-worker when going on **foo.fr**. This is because the service-worker won't follow the 301 redirection and serve the old cache instead.

A quick fix to this is : https://blog.hackages.io/migrating-a-service-worker-from-an-old-domain-to-your-new-domain-69236418051c

**Though what if you buy an expired domain name which had a PWA on it ?** You don't get the previous traffic cause you don't even know there is a service-worker caching it. And even if you know it, you may never be able to fix the problem if you don't know on which route it used to be served.

**And what if you loose access to foo.fr ?** Your old users will have a broken website, which is worse than having no website or a new website (from the new owner).

I couldn't find how long the service-workers are cached by the browser.

Am I wrong about all this ? If not this is really worrying...

Comment: See continuation of the discussion here https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/1480